# Is not accessible in this context because it is friend

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, cryptography, saml

I pulled some code from another C# project and converted it to vb but now I get the error:

`Is not accessible in this context because it is friend`

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography  

Public Shared Sub Sign()
  CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(GetType(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256")
End Sub
```

[image]

The [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.internal.codesigning.rsapkcs1sha256signaturedescription?view=netframework-4.8) required is `System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning` but this namespace does not seem to have `RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription`.

The namespace that is being imported is `System.Security.Cryptography` but I am starting to think this is being derived from the wrong library.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Namespace System.Security.Cryptography
  Friend Class RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription
    Inherits RSAPKCS1SignatureDescription
    Public Sub New()
  End Class
End Namespace
```

---

Could anyone offer insight into this error message?

This error does not seem indictive of what Microsoft says it is:

**Error ID**: BC30389

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30389

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how the error message refers to `System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription`? That's the class that your code is referring to and that class is declared `Friend`, so that's why you can't use it. If you want the `System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription` class then that's the namespace you need to import.

---

The `System.Deployment` namespace first needs adding to your project in order to reference the `Internal.CodeSigning` libraries.

[image]